# Open a password protected Word document in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I need to open the Password protected word document in VBA
It is asking for the password, how to open via code
Code:

```
Dim DPDoc
Dim DPApp
Dim DPPath
DPPath = "C:\MyFolder\PwdProtectdFile.docx"
Set DPApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
' It is asking for the password here 
DPDoc = DPApp.Documents.Open(DPPath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add an argument :

```
Dim YourOwnPassword As String
YourOwnPassword = "TestPWD"
DPDoc = DPApp.Documents.Open(DPPath, PasswordDocument:=YourOwnPassword)
```

Src : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff835182.aspx

Comment: Am getting Run-time error '448' "Named argument not found"

So I changed to 
    DPDoc = DPApp.Documents.Open(DPPath, Password = YourOwnPassword)

Now it is prompting for the password still. Seemed it has not taken into the consideration. Can anyone please help

Comment: @udhayakumar : My bad, for word it seems it should be `PasswordDocument` and not just `Password`! See the edit